# Google Chrome save an image that is no longer on the web

Tags: google-chrome, images, copy-paste, save-as

I've got probably a unique situation where I need to save some images that I have open in Google Chrome, however they don't exist anymore on the Internet. To make matters more complicated, it's important for my particular purpose to get the exact bytes of the image.

I would think logically, just right click and 'Save Image As' but what that does is try to download the image again from the original URL. That fails, and results in saving essentially a blank file.

I can right click and 'Copy Image', however I am not sure where I can paste that to get back the exact bytes of the image. Doing that step in two different applications then saving gives me two different files that look the same but have different contents.

The images are still open in the browser. How can I save these images exactly as they were retrieved? Or is that now impossible to do?

Edit: I thought, just unplug the cord. But no. Apparently the 'Save Image As' feature entirely doesn't work if you are disconnected from the internet.

Comment: seems to be an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are the two options you save them? What's the difference? Why do you need the exact picture? Is it fine the exact picture displayed, or do you need the exact picture that was available on the net?

Comment: I need the exact bytes, and the reason for that is complicated. If I was to find the image again, I need to know if it's the same image, and without the bytes I can't do that practically.

Comment: You could rummage around in the cache ( %AppData%\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache ) and look for it.

Comment: There are hundreds of randomly named files without any extensions. Any idea how to find it in there or even determine that it's there?

Comment: Doesn't simply dragging the image from the web page to your desktop do it? It does on Mac, idk about Windows.

Comment: Before your comments, I had given up on this. As best I can tell, that seems to have worked. Which is weird why it's so hard and easy at the same time. Thank you so much.

Comment: funnily enough in mozilla some time between 2001-2003  I definitely accidentally moved files from their proper location to a temp directory then deleted the temp directory, then realised i'd deleted the files.. and in retrospect should've copied the files to the temp directory.. I was however, able to right click the images and do save as. and put them back in their location! (at least i think that was what I did)!  but that was firefox and then.

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that while almost every other option including the cache or Free Clipboard Viewer were not helpful at all, simply dragging the images into a folder works.

I have confirmed this with another image, and the bytes seem to match. The same signature bytes are in all the images.

Thanks so much to Tetsujin for this answer.